# Try to have a truncate text on two lines with truncate of the beggining of the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, saas

I Try to have a truncate text on two lines with truncate of the beggining of the text.
It has to look like that:

...  to long

for this div

But I did not find the solution. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is [tute from David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis-left) which shows one method using `text-overflow: ellipsis` in concert with `direction: rtl;`

```css
.ellipsize-left {
  /* Standard CSS ellipsis */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
  /* Beginning of string */
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='ellipsize-left'>
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. It works but how to put the text on two lines with that technique, I can truncate the text but cant put the text on a second line.